# Sails socket listening on range events

Tags: sockets, sails.js

I have a problem with sails sockets listening on events, based on range for x, y coordinates.

My sails server-side is basic, and by default: no index action described, because blueprints does the magic. And inside my custom route and controller action, after i update MapEvent model, I just call the

`Mapevents.publishCreate(MapEvent);`

client looks like this:

```
var db_query = {
    "x": {"greaterThanOrEqual": 55},
    "x": {"lessThanOrEqual": 75},
    "y": {"greaterThanOrEqual": 25},
    "y": {"lessThanOrEqual": 45},
};

io.socket.get('/mapevents?limit=10000&where=' + JSON.stringify(db_query), function(events) {
    console.log(events) // all is ok, i get results of this range
});

io.socket.on('mapevents', function(event){
    console.log(event); // bad, i get results of everything
});
```

How can i get mapevents for x/y coordinates range?

Answer (score 0):

So far my own best idea to solve it was:

For every user in database i will add x_from, x_to, y_from, y_to.
After every user changes its view, i will update database with the user view scope. So, after user drags the screen to the left, he sees then another coordinates scope.

Then every user listens on its own "user_id" socket room, for example "1".

And in node.js server side after any MapEvent update, the MapEvent x,y coordinates changes (or not). And then i will fetch all the users who's screen is inbetween these coordinates. So i will get like 3 users are watching that area where this MapEvent was changed.

So in server side i will call MapEvent.publishCreate for all 3 rooms with these user_ids which observes that x,y area.